# Conditional Formatting based on ranges in SAP Design Studio score card

Tags: business-objects

I use SAP HANA as a data source.
I am trying to apply conditional formatting on a measure in a scorecard.
For example:

```
If Value<5 then Red.  
If Value>=5 then Green.
```

But I don't find any way to use this range for conditional formatting

I am able to apply conditional formatting on dimensions in `Cell -> Cell Background -> Dimension Member Content -> in Keys` to match give attribute's value and colour.

But I cannot find a way to apply conditional formatting of measures based on ranges.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use ";" or the stated conditions. For instance, (less than) 5 (red), equal to or greater than 5. (green). Or, use "between", 0;4 (red), 5;10 (green).